# Java- Where does the variable name or Identifier gets stored, Stack or Heap?

Tags: java, object, variables, heap-memory, stack-memory

Where does the identifiers or variable name gets stored in java? I understand that objects get stored in heap and variable gets store in heap or stack depending on the type and scope of variable. Can we debug or write any program to confirm it?

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Names of **fields** are stored as part of the class metadata, in formerly-PermGen now-Metaspace.

**Array elements** don't have names, only numbers. [(Cue Patrick McGoohan.)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0061287/reference)

Names of **method and constructor parameters and local variables and handler parameters** are stored only in the debug-symbols info in the classfile, if that option is selected. They aren't needed by the JVM because the compiler has mapped them to stack-frame slot numbers used in the bytecode.

Answer (score 2):

Variable names are stored in "method area" (which is part of the permgen.) along with other class meta-data.

There is a special area to hold class meta-data called method area. This is part of permgen (which was in heap before java 8) now it has been moved to metaspace

Comment: Are you saying that class meta-data and Variable names gets stored in heap?

Comment: Updated my answer. @JeetendraChoudhary

Comment: Thank you and where is this metaspace just curious. And does it matters, I mean is it somehow useful for developers or just good to know thing.

Comment: @JeetendraChoudhary - Permgen data has been moved to native memory space which is different from your heap space.

Answer (score 0):

Variable names are stored in method area of permanent generation. Object are always stored in the Heap, but object reference stored in the stack.

Comment: I think the OP is asking about the "field names" here not field data